# How to ensure the same controller instance is referenced in two different places in ember

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

tl;dr:  Ember is creating two instances of an ArrayController when I want only one.  How do I ensure that my code is always referencing the same one?

#### The scenario

Using ember, I am trying to create a section of a page where potential buyers can select from two sets of options, then click a button to accept those options and redirect to another page based on their choices.  Example:

[image]

However, when I click the button, it uses whatever was selected when the page first loaded, ignoring any actions in between.

### Let's work through the code

When you click the Reserve Now button, it triggers an action on the LessonPackagesController:

```
#handlebars template
<a {{action bookLesson on="click"}}>Reserve Now</a>
```

Here's the action it triggers: (If you don't understand emberscript, imagine it's just pseudocode... that runs)

```
#LessonPackagesController
bookLesson: ->
  window.location = @bookingUrl
```

The location it points to is currently outside the ember application, so I don't think transitionToRoute and its sibling methods are viable.

@bookingUrl is a computed property on the controller.

```
#LessonPackagesController
+computed chosenPackage lessonType
bookingUrl: ->
  url = "/instructors/#{@id}/lesson_bookings/new"
  url += "/#{@lessonType}"
  url += "/#{@chosenPackage.name}" if @chosenPackage
  url
```

To simplify, I've started out by setting @lessonType to a default ('private'), and we don't have to worry about how @id is being fetched, because it's working.

Before we get into the details of how @chosenPackage is updated, I put together some code that logs every time @chosenPackage is updated, confirming that both @chosenPackage and @bookingUrl are being updated as expected.

```
#LessonPackagesController
+observer chosenPackage
yolo: ->
  console.log(@bookingUrl)
```

Whenever I click a lesson package, for example the six-lesson package, I see the following in my console: `/instructors/58/lesson_bookings/new/private/six`.  This is exactly as I expected.

However, when I click the Reserve Now button, I get the following: `/instructors/58/lesson_bookings/new/private`.  This is the @bookingUrl that exists before the @chosenPackage is updated.

#### The plot thickens

In further tests, I put a @content log in 'yolo', and found that the content was... an empty array.  Putting this together with the null @chosenPackage in @bookLesson, I surmised that I was accessing two different instances of LessonPackagesController.  Here's how I access it when updating the @chosenPackage (which triggers the @yolo function):

```
class App.LessonPackageController extends Ember.ObjectController
  needs: ['lessonPackages']
  selectMe: ->
    @chosenPackage = this

  +computed chosenPackage
  chosen: ->
    this == @chosenPackage

  chosenPackageBinding: 'controllers.lessonPackages.chosenPackage'
  chosenPackage: ''
```

I know that all the LessonPackageController instances interact with the same LessonPackagesController because selecting one will deselect the current chosen package.  However, it happens to be different than the instance which @bookLesson is called on.

#### How do I ensure those two instances are in fact one instance, the same instance?

Comment: I think it's cool that you are using EmberScript, but I can't make heads or tails of it. Maybe you can update the question to use Javascript so more people will be able to help.

Comment: I think your suspicions might be correct that there are two separate controllers, but I'm not seeing any reason why that would happen from what you posted. Is there any way you can post some more complete code?

Comment: @LukeMelia you don't use EmberScript? You are missing out :P.